# R Shiny App integration with Drupal 7 - how to read Drupal cookies?

Tags: r, drupal-7, shiny

I have a Drupal 7 site and I am build a Shiny app that I want to integrate into a page on my site. The app will be integrated as an iframe (of the app which will be on a subdomain of that Drupal site).

I want only specific logged users to have access to my app so my thinking was like this. 
Shiny app Reads the cookie from the Drupal site and checks the database of the Drupal site for that cookie.

How would I go about checking the Drupal database for the cookie I obtain? I looked at the Drupal database and the sessions table doesn't contain anything resembling that cookie, is some hashing going on? How would I access that data through R?

Answer (score 1):

This function is responsible for the user session cookie creation : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21session.inc/function/drupal_session_regenerate/7.x

I think an easier solution will be to create an url in your drupal to check if the user is logged in, then if you have the cookie in your app, you just have to request this url with the cookie in the request header (well in theory, i will let you check if it works...for testing purpose just send all cookies, no need to find exactly wich one is needed).

The drupal url will just have to return user_is_logged_in() result:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items=array();
  $items['am-i-logged-in'] => array(
      'title' => 'Check if user is logged in or not',
      'page callback' => '_user_is_logged_in_callback',
   );
}

function _user_is_logged_in_callback() { 
  if(user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_json_output("ok"); 
  }
  else {
    drupal_json_output("ko"); 
  }
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Then you just have to request www.yoursitename.com/am-i-logged-in with the cookie in the header of your http request to your Drupal server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test it, and  report back. The link you provided might be wrong though.

Comment: Corrected the link, my bad. Basically drupal_session_regenerate is called each time an user is connecting (or dysconnecting), so the mecanic for the user cookie and session id is there.